# Does String Theory explain wave-particle duality?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, string-theory, wave-particle-duality

Does string theory explain the weird things that happens at the quantum level, especially wave-particle duality?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Actually, too broad.

Answer (score 5):

I do not think so. As a matter of fact strings must be "quantized" to produce "quantum" physics. So the quantum structure (including all apparently weird things) is assumed *a priori* even dealing with strings. It is deeper than string theory.

Answer (score 3):

No. You quantize strings using the same methods as for other classical theories, but these methods are postulated, so you can't use this to explain anything. There is also no such thing as wave-particle duality, that's a terribly out-of-date term. We have neither particles nor waves, but instead wave-functions and operators that correspond to observables.